# failover with crm - current server

Tags: failover, crm

crm status is kind of confusing :-(
Which of the 2 nodes is the currently selected one and which one is the alternative machine for failover scenario?

```
 crm status
 ============
 Last updated: Sun Jul 29 20:07:17 2012
 Stack: Heartbeat
 Current DC: testsrvm2.test-domain.biz (d5eb712f-d246-4363-a4e3-73fec90be179) - partition with quorum
 Version: 1.0.9-74392a28b7f31d7ddc86689598bd23114f58978b
 2 Nodes configured, 1 expected votes
 1 Resources configured.
 ============

 Online: [ testsrvm2.test-domain.biz testsrvm1.test-domain.biz ]

  Resource Group: IPFailover
      ip1        (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started testsrvm1.test-domain.biz
      ip1arp     (ocf::heartbeat:SendArp):       Started testsrvm1.test-domain.biz
```

Thx

Answer (score 0):

From your crm status output, all the resources defined in the group IPFailover should be running on `testsrvm1.test-domain.biz`, as indicated by the last two lines.

For which alternative machine it may run the resources on, it should usually run the resources in all nodes in that cluster, which is the two nodes on the line begin with "Online:". However, if crm config have some location rule to prevent it from running on some node, it won't run on that.